# Date Difference less than 15 minutes in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

Below is my query, in which in the last line I am trying to see if the difference between the dates is within 15 minutes. But whenever I run the below query.

```
SELECT TT.BUYER_ID , COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT testingtable1.buyer_id, testingtable1.item_id, testingtable1.created_time from (select user_id, prod_and_ts.product_id as product_id, prod_and_ts.timestamps as timestamps from testingtable2 LATERAL VIEW explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts where to_date(from_unixtime(cast(prod_and_ts.timestamps as BIGINT))) = '2012-07-09') prod_and_ts RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT buyer_id, item_id, rank(buyer_id), created_time, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_time)
FROM (
    SELECT buyer_id, item_id, created_time
    FROM testingtable1
    where to_date(from_unixtime(cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_time) as int))) = '2012-07-09'
    DISTRIBUTE BY buyer_id
    SORT BY buyer_id, created_time desc
) a
WHERE rank(buyer_id) < 5) testingtable1 ON (testingtable1.item_id = prod_and_ts.product_id AND testingtable1.BUYER_ID = prod_and_ts.USER_ID 
AND abs(datediff(testingtable1.created_time,FROM_UNIXTIME(cast(prod_and_ts.timestamps as BIGINT)))) <= 15) where prod_and_ts.product_id IS NULL ORDER BY testingtable1.buyer_id, testingtable1.created_time desc) TT GROUP BY TT.BUYER_ID;
```

I always get the exception as-

```
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 10:144 Both Left and Right Aliases
Encountered in Join 15
```

Is there anything wrong with my query? Or in Hive we cannot calculate difference between dates in minutes? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your join. From the [the Hive language manual](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/language_manual/joins.html):

> Only equality joins, outer joins, and left semi joins are supported in
>   Hive. Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality
>   conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a
>   map/reduce job.