# Date comparison in Hive

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, ddl

I'm working with Hive and I have a table structured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id INT,
  created TIMESTAMP,
  some_value BIGINT
);
```

I need to find every row in `t1` that is less than 180 days old. The following query yields no rows even though there is data present in the table that matches the search predicate.

```
select * 
from t1 
where created > date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), 180);
```

What is the appropriate way to perform a date comparison in Hive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
where unix_timestamp() - created < 180 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Date math is usually simplest if you can just do it with the actual timestamp values.

Or do you want it to only cut off on whole days? Then I think the problem is with how you are converting back and forth between ints and strings. Try:

```
where created > unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),180),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Walking through each UDF:

1. `unix_timestamp()` returns an int: current time in seconds since epoch
2. `from_unixtime(,'yyyy-MM-dd')` converts to a string of the given format, e.g. '2012-12-28'
3. `date_sub(,180)` subtracts 180 days from that string, and returns a new string in the same format.
4. `unix_timestamp(,'yyyy-MM-dd')` converts that string back to an int

If that's all getting too hairy, you can always write a UDF to do it yourself.

Comment: Fantastic explanation of the solution I ended up using. One question - will the comparison between `TIMESTAMP`/`STRING` and an `INT` work out in this case?

Comment: Following up - the `TIMESTAMP`/`STRING` to `INT` compare works. Thanks for that information, it simplifies the query nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you may also use **datediff**. Then the where clause would be
in case of String timestamp (jdbc format) :

```
datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), created) < 180;
```

in case of Unix epoch time:

```
datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), from_unixtime(created)) < 180;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe it's a Hive bug dealing with the **timestamp** type. I've been trying to use it recently and getting incorrect results. 
If I change your schema to use a string *instead of* timestamp, and supply values in the

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

format, then the select query worked for me.

According to the documentation, Hive should be able to convert a BIGINT representing epoch seconds to a timestamp, and that all existing datetime UDFs work with the timestamp data type.

with this simple query:

> select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), cast(unix_timestamp() as
>   timestamp) from test_tt limit 1;

I would expect both fields to be the same, but I get:

> 2012-12-29 00:47:43     1970-01-16 16:52:22.063

I'm seeing other weirdness as well.

Comment: It looks like this is reported in [HIVE-3454](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3454), but there hasn't been any work done to fix it as the Hive maintainers want to ensure backwards compatibility with the broken behavior.

Comment: @JeremiahPeschka Thanks, plus has workaround... I should search for my other timestamp issues there as well.

Answer (score 3):

TIMESTAMP is milliseconds
unix_timestamp is in seconds
You need to multiply the RHS by 1000.

```
where created > 1000 * date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), 180);
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing this and referring to [Date Difference less than 15 minutes in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589084/date-difference-less-than-15-minutes-in-hive) I came up with a solution. While I'm not sure why Hive doesn't perform the comparison effectively on dates as strings (they should sort and compare lexicographically), the following solution works:

```
FROM (
    SELECT  id, value,
            unix_timestamp(created) c_ts, 
            unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), 180), 'yyyy-MM-dd') c180_ts
    FROM    t1
) x
JOIN t1 t ON x.id = t.id
SELECT  to_date(t.Created), 
        x.id, AVG(COALESCE(x.HighestPrice, 0)), AVG(COALESCE(x.LowestPrice, 0))
WHERE   unix_timestamp(t.Created) > x.c180_ts
GROUP BY to_date(t.Created), x.id ;
```